# Manifold that is Hausdorff and second countable

Tags: manifolds

Why are we usually assume that a manifold $M$ has to be a ***Hausdorff space*** and ***Second countable*** ? Is it really hard to study smooth manifolds without making these assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Whitney's embedding theorem teaches us, that every manifold is locally the image of an $U\to \mathbb{R}^p$ smooth embedding (for a suitable p). That shows that the notion of manifold is quite natural. On the other hand Whitney's theorem doesn't hold without these assumptions.

Comment: So these assumptions rule out manifold that that isn't "look like" $\mathbb{R^n}$ in some sense?

Comment: These assumptions rule out manifolds which are too abstract in the mean that they cannot be embedded in a finite dimensional euclidean space. You can imagine the manifolds as sets in form {f(x)=0} in $\mathbb{R}^p$ where the rank of the Jacobian of f is constant (and less than p). (the Implicit Function Theorem gives us an atlas)